# How to disect if a textbox was Clicked or Tapped Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, monogame

I got the following problem. I have a textbox in my Monogame with XAML project (This uses exactly the same references as a normal XAML project does) and if need to catch if what clicked on the textbox was fired from a mouse or touch. I tried different things

```
txtTest.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerEventHandler(txtTest_PointerPressed), true);
txtTest.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedEventHandler(txtTest_Tapped), true);
```

I added handlers to the events but the problem is Both events are triggered by mouse or touch and I need to separate them because I need to handle them both different.

I searched trough the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox) but couldn't find anything else fitting my problem

Already thanks for the effort.

Comment: Given you have access to txtTest, doesn't it expose the event already? Try txtTest.GotFocus or txtTest.Tapped, from there you can see what is the source of the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TappedEventHandler` will expose a [`TappedRoutedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.tappedroutedeventargs).

This class includes a [`PointerDeviceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.pointerdevicetype) property, which will specify whether the tap occurred via a touch, mouse, or pen.

Comment: A True Hero! Thanks for the immense quick response. Couldn't find it anywhere so I posted with the hope someone would answer it someday, 3 minutes later the answer was given :D

Comment: To follow up on this answer. I used the PointerEventHandler that returned also a Pointer.PointerDeviceType because the pointer event fire's before the element gets Focus the TappedEventHandler fire's after the element gets focus what would be to late for me.